# How to select previous record in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Hello everyone I would like to ask you that how could I select previous record in sql server 2008 like image below if I stand on "ACCOUNTING MANAGER" I would like to select "SELLER"

[image]

Comment: what so You mean by stand?

Comment: what is that `TODATE` of `5000-01-01`... whatever it is surely there is a better way to do whatever that represents.

Answer (score 0):

use cte like create rownumber() using row_number function....

```
with temp as (select *,row_number()over( order by  [tooday] asc) as rn from tablename )

select t1.jobDESC  from  temp t1
join temp t2 on t1.rn =t2.rn-1
where  t2.jobDESC = 'ACCOUNTING MANAGER'
```

Note change tablename  with table name ..

Answer (score 0):

It's a better way to put primary key in the table. So create a primary key in your table.

```
select top 1 t1.* from table1 t1, table1 t2 
where t1.primaryKey = t2.primaryKey - 1 order by primaryKey desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
first of all you need to add one column as Identity.

```
ALTER TABLE Your_TableName ADD AUTOID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Then you need to find the rowID of the record where you are standing right now (i.e. "ACCOUNTING MANAGER").

```
declare @RowID INT
Set @RowID=(Select AUTOID from Your_TableName where JOBDESC="ACCOUNTING MANAGER")
```

AND then

```
select * from Your_TableName where AUTOID=(@RowID-1)
```

@RowID -1  if you want previous record.

@RowID+1   if you want next record.